# Sum for all element of the sum of x for every element

Tags: summation, notation

Let $i$ be an element of the set $S$.
Suppose that you need to calculate a sum of many rates $\rho$ for every element $i$, and then the sum these sums for all elements of the set $S$.

How do I write the equation without introducing a new variable to represent the sum for every element?

The only writing that comes to my mind is the following:

$$\sum_{\forall i} \sum_{i \in S} \rho$$

Unfortunately, this notation is completely wrong and I know it... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following: Let $R_i$ be the set of rates for element $i$, then the sum could be represented by

$$
\sum_{i \in S} \sum_{\rho \in R_i} \rho
$$